# Argue that the following processes are Markov chains.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables such that $P\{X_i=j\}=\alpha_j,j\geq0$. Say that a record occurs at a time $n$ if $X_n>max\{X_1,...,X_{n-1}\}$ where $X_0=-\infty$, and if a record does not occur at time $n$ call $X_n$ the record value. Let $R_i$ denote the $i$th record value.

(a) Argue that $\{R_i,i\geq1\}$ is a Markov chain and compute its transition probabilities.

(b) Let $T_i$ denote the time between the $i$th and $(i+1)$st record. Is $\{T,i\geq1\}$ a Markov chain? What about $\{(R_i,T_i),i\geq1\}$? Compute transition probabilities where appropriate.
(c) Let $\displaystyle{S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}T_i,n\geq1}$. Argue that $\{S_n,n\geq1\}$ is a Markov chain when the $X_i$ are continuous and find its transition probabilities.

**My Attempt**

Since it says argue, I'm assuming it doesn't require a formal proof and just an explanation?

(a) We can see that $\{R_i,i\geq1\}$ is a Markov chain because the probability that we record a value only depends on the previous value. It does not matter what precedes it because that number will be less than the number after it. For example, number $X_n$ will be greater than $X_{n-1}$ since we only record value $X_n$ if this was true. Then the next number will only be recorded if it is greater than $X_n$. It does not matter what $X_{n-1}$ is.

(b) I do not think that $\{T_i,i\geq1\}$ is a Markov chain because the probability of the time between the $i$th record and the $(i+1)$st record does not depend on what the previous time was.

I don't quite understand what $\{(R_i,T_i),i\geq1\}$ represents.

(c) Since we are looking at the sum of the times, we know that the $S_n=S_{n-1}+T_{n+1}$. So we can see that the probability of the next value depends only on the immediately previous value.

The part that I am having trouble with is the transition probabilities. Can I get some pointers on how to find these? It would also be great to know if my explanations made sense. Thank you.